# VueJS how to delay method to execute after render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have button that executes parse method

```
parse: function()
{
    this.json.data = getDataFromAPI();
    applyColor();
},
applyColor: function()
{
    for (var i=0; i<this.json.data.length; i++)
    {
        var doc = document.getElementById(this.json.data[i].id);
        doc.style.background = "red";
    }
}
```

The problem is that applyColor cannot execute properly because `this.json.data` is not rendered until `parse()` function ends.

I'd want to achieve something like this:

```
this.json.data = getDataFromAPI(); 
exit parse() method
execute applyColor();
```

but without huge changes to code -> maybe some kind of "put that aside for later" like

```
this.json.data = getDataFromAPI(); 
promise(500ms) applyColor();
exit parse() method
500ms
executes applyColor()
```

What I've been trying?

> this.$forceUpdate(); before apply

Answer (score 1):

You can use the computed properties to trigger an update based on the update of other properties:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

But I don't fully understand why you loop through the elements of the dataset in the applyColor method and why you don't loop it in the Vue template with creating a CSS class for the style like this:

```
<div v-for="element, index in json.data" :key="index" class="bg-red">{{element}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this

getDataFromAPI should be promise, when data comes you send 'this' variable as a reference using self.

```
parse: function()
{
    var self = this;
    getDataFromAPI().then((data)=>{
     self.json.data = data
     self.applyColor();
    })

},
applyColor: function()
{
    for (var i=0; i<this.json.data.length; i++)
    {
        var doc = document.getElementById(this.json.data[i].id);
        doc.style.background = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async and await seems like it will work with the least changes of code. You need to define parse with async and `this.json.data = await getDataFromApi()`, doing it this way , the code will execute in the exact order you have it on description, so applyColors will have this.json.data . Ref: https://javascript.info/async-await